# Pass a (large) string to 'grep' instead of a file name

Tags: linux, terminal

Is it possible to pass a relatively large string to `grep` or can it only accept a file?

Note that I'm not talking about piping output to grep, but doing something like:

```
grep 'hello' 'hello world'
```

(which of course doesn't work, at least not like that)

Comment: Maybe pipe some kind of text data to `grep`? So maybe something like `printf "various\ntext to grep here" | grep "text"` will produce "text to grep here"

Answer (score 52):

It's possible. Try this:

```
grep 'hello' <<< 'hello world'
```

You can also pass a variable containing string instead:

```
str='hello world'
grep 'hello' <<< $str
```

Comment: For reference, this is a **here string**. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Comment: quote from wiki: *available in **bash**, **ksh**, or **zsh***

Comment: Notably, **this is not available in sh**, you'll need bash or another shell mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 14):

`grep` doesn't have an option to interpret its command-line arguments as text to be searched. The normal way to `grep` a string is to pipe the string into `grep`'s standard input:

```
$ echo 'There once was a man from Nantucket
Who kept all his cash in a bucket.
    But his daughter, named Nan,
    Ran away with a man
And as for the bucket, Nantucket.' | grep -i nan
There once was a man from Nantucket
    But his daughter, named Nan,
And as for the bucket, Nantucket.
$
```

As you see here, you can `echo` strings containing more than one line of text. You can even type them into the shell interactively, if you like.

If this doesn't meet your needs, maybe you could explain why piping isn't an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 7):

**Pipe it into `grep`**

Why not just:

```
echo 'hello world' | grep 'hello'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106526/how-can-i-grep-complex-strings-in-variables